# Code to find factors of a number in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

So here is my code to find the factors of a number n, excluding n and 1.

```
factors :: Int -> [Int]
factors n = [x | x <- [2..(intSquareRoot n)], n `mod` x ==0]

intSquareRoot :: Int -> Int
intSquareRoot n = intSq n
  where
    intSq x
      | x*x > n = intSq (x - 1)
      | otherwise = x
```

it finds the factors of n upto sqrt(n), then I want to add the rest of factors. The code I want would look like this

```
factors :: Int -> [Int]
factors n = [x | x <- [2..(intSquareRoot n)], n `mod` x ==0]
          ++[1/x | x <- [2..(intSquareRoot n)], n `mod` x ==0]
```

But Haskell gives me the error that it expects a fractional number, which is understandable because I am dividing it. However, I know that for all x satisfying the conditions of the list, n/x will be an integer. How do I get around this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even if `x` is an `Int`, ```1 `quot` x``` will always be 0 or `-1`.  Did you mean `n / x`?  And to get around it, you can use the `quot` function instead, and there's the `quotRem` function which calculates the modulus at the same time.

Comment: since your question was really about how to do integer division in Haskell, I marked it as a duplicate of this popular-looking answer that explains `div`, `mod`, `quot`, and `rem` with more information than provided in my comment above.

Comment: @did you mean `n/x` in the 2nd list comprehension? (i.e. `div n x`). You don't need to search for them again, they are already at your disposal in the 1st comprehension: `factors n = let xqs = [(x,q) | x<-[2..isqrt n], x*x<n, let (q,r)=quotRem n x, r==0] in map fst xqs ++ [x|let x=isqrt n, x*x==n] ++ reverse (map snd xqs)`.